What would cause poor rear shifting?
Ever since my rear cable snapped this past January (and I replaced the cable), shifting has been less than ideal.  The new cable helped, but it is still nothing like new.  I typically replace the cables proactively yearly, but wanted to see how close they were to failing and what that experience would be like so if I were to encounter it in the field, how I could handle it.  So, I let it go nearly 2 years before it failed.
I did replace the rear derailleur cable and housing and adjusted the shifting entirely myself, perhaps that is the issue.  The chain is less than .5% wear and the cassette was new at the time I replaced the chain.  It seemingly shifts fine on the stand, but when riding, not so much.  When I shift while riding, I do let up significantly in effort but try to maintain pedaling speed so the chain is never forced into position.
I am thinking that perhaps the rear derailleur hanger is bent, or the B-screw needs adjusted.  I can shift to the biggest cog in the back from my large chain ring and the rear derailleur cage does not hit the cassette.
When I say poor shifting, it hesitates both advancing forward to the next gear and coming back to an easier gear.  I have previously adjusted the barrel adjuster on the derailleur itself, but that ended up causing the derailleur to advanced 2 gears before settling correctly on 1 gear ahead.  I would just say, sloppy, not laser sharp.
I have the B-screw adjusted as close to the cassette as possible so that it can shift to the biggest cog in the cassette.  If I remove more tension, then the cage will be going into the cassette.
Any ideas?

Cabling is a common cause of this problem, as you recently replaced the cable, check it is not pinched or binding with tight radius curves etc. (Although I expect not as you do this regularly).
A bent hanger would be my best guess. Alignment is possibly without the correct tools, you can jury-rig your own, but I would suggest using the proper tool. Possibly a job for your LBS as it won't take long so should cost a lot less than the tool.
From here look at the original problem - the broken cable. This should not happen and may point to a route cause of the problem (or may not). Check the derailleur for damage. Check for wear spring and motion is smooth and no slop, check the jockey wheels - derailleurs have to be pretty badly worn to cause poor shifting.
Shifter will pretty much work or not, so park this till last.
From here we are into drivetrain wear. How old is the cassette, how many chains has it been through and how worn were they when replaced.  When was the current chain last replaced (before or after the shifter cable). Did that chain/cassette ever shift smoothly?

That is aligning with my thoughts.  The cassette and chain were replaced together.  The chain is nearing .5% wear and will need replaced, I usually do 2 or 3 chains per cassette or when the chain starts skipping on the cassette.

I don't know if this is related, but I also switched from an FSA MegaExo crankset to a Shimano GRX crankset (and matching bottom bracket).

@John Doe - unlikely, although if the chainline changed it could be related.

As we established in the other question, the chainline did in fact change about 2mm outwards.

Cables don't last forever, so the fact that it broke after 2 years is not surprising, that would be roughly 10,000 - 12,000 miles, a lot of shifts.  I had previously replaced them every year / 5,000 miles, before it was a problem.
